# What does Google Search Console look like when you have approximately 1,000 sites?

Tags: google-search-console, menu, accounts

When one has a few sites, this is how the Google Search Console menu looks like when you change the property:

[image: Sample menu on Search Console]

But if you grow to manage approximately 1,000 sites, what does it look like in the Google Search Console property changer - all 1,000 properties listed in a single column? All of them together would feel a bit clunky wouldn't it?

Comment: The list just scrolls. That's why there's a search function at the top of the list.

Comment: This seems very theoretical. I can't imagine anybody registering 1000 websites to a single Google Search Console account.  That would be a lot of time spent just with the registration and verifications.